# Relations beetween apache processes and pageloads/views /hits

Tags: ubuntu, centos, httpd, apache2

When I run the command `ps aux`, I see many entries `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start` (In Ubuntu machine) and `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` (In Centos). I have read fro somewhere that each of those entries is an apache process, which is created beforehand to be ready for the future request to the server.

So, from what I understand, each of those apache processes is to serve http request and it dies off after the job is done, and other processes will be created to get ready for other future requests.

What I'm not clear is, each apache process will serve a pageload or a hit ? (Since each pageload can have a few tens of hit).

I am asking this question because I am seeing 2 different behaviours from Ubuntu and Centos. I am more familiar with Ubuntu, and my Ubuntu machines have never encountered high load problems when I have a lot of hits to non-existent pages (When I say non-existent pages, it means the files does not exist in the server and it is not rewritten to a php file by a .htaccess file)

However, recently I have to manage a Centos server. I see some bad bots just throws 20-30 hits to non-existent pages within 1-2 seconds, and each time it happens the average load shoots up very high, and I also see a lot of `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` entries from `ps aux` command.

So I guess Centos uses up one httpd process for each hit, and in ubuntu each apache process can be used for multiple hits. Is this correct speculation? If that is correct, I think Centos is very inefficient compared to Ubuntu.

Could anyone clarify those points so that I can see what I am missing?

Thank you very much!

**Update 1**:

I also see another difference: When I open an url from ubuntu machines, a `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` process is created, and this process is still there for very long time (hours) even though the pageload is completed within 1-2 seconds. So I guess this php process is holding some cache information so that it can be used to serve the next page request (I don't see a new `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` process when I continue to browse to another page)

But in Centos machine, when I visit a page, if I am lucky I can see a `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi` process, and this process almost disappears immediately after 1-2 seconds

**Update 2**

Here is the content of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (Ubuntu)

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

And here is one part of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (Centos) (Other parts are vhost for domains, I think it doesn't have any useful information)

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
#   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#   DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  USE INCLUDE FILES IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE
#   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#
#   Direct modifications to the Apache configuration file WILL be lost upon subsequent
#   regeneration of this configuration file, or an Apache update.
#
#   To have your modifications retained, you should create/edit administrator-specific
#   include files:
#
#       /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf
#       /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf
#       /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

##################################################
##################################################
#
# cPanel & WHM controlled Apache configuration
#
##################################################
##################################################

Include "/etc/apache2/conf.modules.d/*.conf"

# Administrator locations for safely altering httpd.conf
Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_main_global.conf"

# These are hard-coded values that are required by cPanel & WHM
PidFile /run/apache2/httpd.pid
User nobody
Group nobody
ExtendedStatus On
LogLevel warn
# You can change this by using WHM, and navigating to the 'Basic cPanel & WHM Setup' -> 'Contact Information' interface.
ServerAdmin root@server1.domain.com

# You can change this by using WHM, and navigating to the 'Networking Setup' => 'Change Hostname' interface.
ServerName sv1.howhubs.com

# You can change this by using WHM, and navigating to the 'Apache Configuration' -> 'Global Configuration' interface.
TraceEnable Off
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens ProductOnly
FileETag None

<Directory "/">

      AllowOverride None

    Options 
</Directory>

StartServers 5
<IfModule prefork.c>
    MinSpareServers 5
    MaxSpareServers 10
</IfModule>

ServerLimit 256
MaxRequestWorkers 150
MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
Timeout 300


<IfModule rewrite_module>
# Global DCV Exclude
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ 

# Exclude proxy subdomains as we need rewrites to capture the DCV requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:autoconfig|autodiscover|cpanel|cpcalendars|cpcontacts|webdisk|webmail|whm)\.
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
</IfModule>



# You can change this by using WHM, and navigating to the 'Apache Configuration' -> 'DirectoryIndex Priority' interface.
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php5 index.php4 index.php3 index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.jp index.phtml index.shtml index.xhtml index.html index.htm index.wml Default.html Default.htm default.html default.htm home.html home.htm index.js
</IfModule>

# You can change this by using WHM, and navigating to the 'Apache Configuration' -> 'Memory Usage Restrictions' interface.

# This setting is required by cPanel & WHM in order to provide access to a default webpage when none exists
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Required cPanel security policy: Disallow remote access to .htaccess, .htpasswd, .user.ini, and php.ini files

<Files ~ "^error_log$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

<FilesMatch "^(\.ht(access|passwds?)|\.user\.ini|php\.ini)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?controlpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?kpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecontrolpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securewhm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/swhmredirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail/ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
    ScriptAliasMatch ^/?whm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/whmredirect.cgi

    Alias /bandwidth /usr/local/bandmin/htdocs/
    Alias /img-sys /usr/local/cpanel/img-sys/
    Alias /java-sys /usr/local/cpanel/java-sys/
    Alias /mailman/archives /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/
    Alias /pipermail /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/
    Alias /sys_cpanel /usr/local/cpanel/sys_cpanel/

    ScriptAlias /cgi-sys /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/
    ScriptAlias /mailman /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/cgi-bin/

</IfModule>

# This can be configured in the cPanel 'Leech Protection' interface.
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap LeechProtect prg:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
    Mutex file:/run/apache2 rewrite-map
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddType application/x-tar .tgz
    AddType text/vnd.wap.wml .wml
    AddType image/vnd.wap.wbmp .wbmp
    AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript .wmls
    AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc .wmlc
    AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc .wmlsc

    # These extensions are used to redirect incoming requests to WHM
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl

    # This is used for custom error documents
    AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
</IfModule>

# You can change this by using WHM, and updating the 'Tweak Settings' -> 'System' -> 'Allow server-info' option.
<IfModule status_module>
    # This is used by the WHM 'Apache Status' application
    <Location /whm-server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </Location>

</IfModule>

# Required cPanel security policy: disable userdir when mod_ruid2 or mpm_itk or mod_passenger are loaded
<IfModule userdir_module>
    UserDir public_html

    <IfModule ruid2_module>
        UserDir disabled
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
        UserDir disabled
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        UserDir disabled
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>


<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
    # NOTE: "combined" and "common" are required by WHM
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

    # access_log format can be set in WHM under 'Basic cPanel & WHM Setup'
    CustomLog logs/access_log combined
</IfModule>


# The Listen port can be updated using 'Tweak Settings' -> 'System',
# However, if you have any Apache Reserved IPs, then this Tweak setting will
# be ignored. Instead, each IP on your system (excluding Apache Reserved IPs)
# will be listed here.
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::]:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    # cipher and protocol directives can be set in WHM under 'Apache Configuration' -> 'Global Configuration'
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:!DSS
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

    <IfModule socache_shmcb_module>
        SSLUseStapling on
        SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/run/apache2/stapling_cache_shmcb(256000)

        # Prevent browsers from failing if an OCSP server is temporarily broken.
        SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
        SSLStaplingErrorCacheTimeout 60
        SSLStaplingFakeTryLater off
        SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 3
        SSLSessionCache shmcb:/run/apache2/ssl_gcache_data_shmcb(1024000)
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !socache_shmcb_module>
        SSLSessionCache dbm:/run/apache2/ssl_gcache_data_dbm
    </IfModule>

    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
    Mutex                   file:/run/apache2 ssl-cache
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

    # The Listen port can be updated using 'Tweak Settings' -> 'System',
    # However, if you have any Apache Reserved IPs, then this Tweak setting will
    # be ignored. Instead, each IP on your system (excluding Apache Reserved IPs)
    # will be listed here.
    Listen 0.0.0.0:443
    Listen [::]:443

    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl
</IfModule>

Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf"

Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/account_suspensions.conf"
Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/errordocument.conf"

# Administrator locations for safely globally altering all virtualhost configurations
Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf"

ProxyPass /___proxy_subdomain_ws_cpanel  ws://127.0.0.1:2082 max=1 retry=0
ProxyPass /___proxy_subdomain_ws_whm     ws://127.0.0.1:2086 max=1 retry=0
ProxyPass /___proxy_subdomain_ws_webmail ws://127.0.0.1:2095 max=1 retry=0
```

Comment: You need to provide the apache configuration on Ubuntu and CentOS. The difference may be due to a different config parameters.

Comment: Rather than looking at running processes please take a look at your actual configuration. For a larger part the behaviour of Apache HTTPD depends on [which MPM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html) is configured. The main options: [prefork](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html), and [worker](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) result in completely different performance characteristics

Comment: I have added the content of apache configuration files. @HBruijn Ideally I should read the documentaiotn, but the documentation is beyond what I can understand, unfortunately. My main question is "apache/httpd process will serve a pageload or a hit"? Since I feel weird that hits to non-existent pages on the centos server also spawn httpd processes and cause high CPU usage, so I hope I can learn something to change its behaviour to make it more similar to ubuntu machines